# is there a way to get the face texture from Augmented Faces in ARCore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I did developed an app which use ARCore for face in hole photography with the back camera (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.avantgardvision.PhotographAR). But now I want to use Augmented Faces with the front camera. Is it possible to get the detected face texture from ARCore face tracker and then used it to another mesh? Do you know such examples?

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thank you. Let say in Face detection API (https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial) which is also from google I can detect the landmarks then draw a circle around the face on the image:

for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
    Face face = faces.valueAt(i);
    for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
        int cx = (int) (landmark.getPosition().x * scale);
        int cy = (int) (landmark.getPosition().y * scale);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 10, paint);
    }
}

Is it possible to do the same with ARCore?